# Network call on alarm times out

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, alarmmanager

I have an app that uses `AlarmManager` to schedule a repeating alarm every X amount of time. When my receiver receives the `Intent`, it has to make a http request.

The alarm itself works fine and triggers when it should. The network call, however, starts timing out when the phone is not in use. To be more specific:

When I schedule it to fire every minute (bad practise, I know, but just to illustrate), the first 5-8 minutes the request succeeds. After that, I get a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`. Sometimes it does succeed, but mostly this happens.

I tried setting the connect/read/write timeouts to a minute, but then I get this exception instead of the one above: `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to myapp.example.com/123.45.67.89:80`.

My code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Consider mApi and myBody to be initialised and valid
        mApi.myPostRequest(myBody).enqueue(new Callback<Void> {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                //Does not get here
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

- as stated before, increasing timeouts
- acquiring a `WakeLock` in
  `onReceive` and releasing it when the call is done (added the
  permission)

Other information:

- The alarm is set using
  `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pendingIntent);` from my
  `Activity`.
- I'm using Retrofit (2.1.0) for the network communication, but you could probably have guessed that from my code ;)

Any ideas on how to get the network call working when the phone is sleeping?

Comment: Sounds like [Doze mode interference](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html). For your Android 5.0+ devices, consider switching to `JobScheduler` and configure the jobs to get control only when there is an Internet connection.

Comment: @jelsief Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @dor506 I didn't continue on this project..

Answer (score 2):

You Should use JobService here, it has many constraint to handle different scenarios and also your Job is guaranteed to be executed by the system.

The problem here is of doze mode, and using JobService this can be resolved easily.

Implementation is also easy all you need to do is create a JobService and inside it's onStartJob() start your network thread and then just dispatch your job.

For more detail

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

> As a general rule, broadcast receivers are allowed to run for up to 10
>   seconds before they system will consider them non-responsive and ANR
>   the app. Since these usually execute on the app's main thread, they
>   are already bound by the ~5 second time limit of various operations
>   that can happen there (not to mention just avoiding UI jank), so the
>   receive limit is generally not of concern. However, once you use
>   {@goAsync }, though able to be off the main thread, the broadcast
>   execution limit still applies, and that includes the time spent
>   between calling this method and ultimately PendingResult.finish().

Further reading says

> If you are taking advantage of this method to have more time to
>   execute, it is useful to know that the available time can be longer in
>   certain situations. In particular, if the broadcast you are receiving
>   is not a foreground broadcast (that is, the sender has not used
>   FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND), then more time is allowed for the receivers
>   to run, allowing them to execute for 30 seconds or even a bit more.
>
> (long work should be punted to another system facility such as
>   [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), or see especially [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html)),

You can try using @goAsync. Or you can switch your logic to [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html)

I haven't tested any of these.

Answer (score 1):

You have a basic mistake in your code - you cannot make requests (or any long running operations) in your broadcast receiver - it dies after ~10 sec so that might be the reason for some of your failures.

You should move the request logic to a service (IntentService) which you'll start from your broadcast receiver and make the request there.

That should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From developer docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the
>   phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.
>   Once onReceive() returns, the Alarm Manager releases this wake lock.
>   This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your
>   onReceive() method completes

In your code onReceive will return before `mApi.myPostRequest(myBody).enqueue ...`task will be executed, then this task probably will be never executed due the CPU will stop as soon onReceive returns.

You said you tested acquiring a WakeLock, but new Android 6.0 Doze mode ignores wakelocks

It seems that OnReceive will have to wait for the task to end

Some ideas:

Checking for some terminate flag in a loop with thread.sleep ?

If the task uses a Thread object then using thread.join() ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`, not `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` to wake up device and you should use a service to do your job started in Received in `onReceive` with `startWakefulService(context, service.class)`. This will ensure that device will fully wake up and do your network call without timeout.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is caused by Doze and Wakelocks being ignored, you should try the tips offered in https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html:

> Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are >deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() >or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 problems in your implementation:

1) if broadcast receiver doesn't get finished executing within 10 seconds then ANR will happen.
2) All network calls are optimized in the background, so when device is wake it may work else will not fire HTTP request to conserve battery and other resources.

what you should do is inside service create a loop (with sleep time of few seconds) that checks time on each iteration and when that time is reached then perform task, I have also faced such issues when tried to upload files to server at an interval of 1 hour, so I decided to work on my own rather than using AlarmManager class...

I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use Foreground service to get your job done.
Refer the official link for dive into [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

By using Foreground service, we can set the interval to start doing an API call in the background without getting affected by the doze mode. follow this [simple example](https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/) that includes complete code and walkthrough.

happy coding. Thanks ;)